# how to change cpu and disk size of slurm image VM in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, slurm

I have deployed slurm cluster to gcp , and currently there are 3 VMs created.

- image
- controller
- login

I wanted to upgrade all three cpu and disk sizes.

The current controller and login VM have been upgraded.

However, in the case of image, it does not enter through ssh communication, so disk cannot be changed, and cpu does not seem to be applied even if it is modified in console.

Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: I deployed [Schedmd-Slurm-GCP](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/schedmd-slurm-public/schedmd-slurm-gcp?project=project-32400&folder=&organizationId=) from Google Cloud Marketplace and by following the commands from [Changing a machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance#changing_a_machine_type) and [gcloud compute disks resize](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/resize) I was able to upgrade the CPU and the Disk size.

Comment: Thank you but i don't use marketpalce ! 
I change the slurm.conf file.

Comment: I was able to deploy a new VM with modified CPU and Disk size values by making changes to the fields “*machine_type*” and “*compute_disk_size_gb*” in the file “/slurm/scripts/config.yaml” on the Controller VM. Can you try this ?